# A technical problem with the server created an error throws when customer is saving in backend magento 2.2.6

Tags: magento2, customer, edit

In the admin section of Magento, Customer edit & update the content and save the customer. It throws an error like:

> A technical problem with the server created an error

. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later.  using Magento 2.2.6, there is no error displayed in log files

Comment: hey did you check post parmas? are you sending it properly means is there any required param which you are not sending in post request?

Comment: Now am able to resolve, since it is happening due to installing third party plugin